# add permission/route on route

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

i created a middleware to be able to block some routes in my laravel application, but isnt working, cant figure out what im doing wrong, here is my code:

ps: im using laravel 5.2

Route:

```
Route::get('secretarea', function(){
    return "this is a secret area";
})->before('admin');
```

AdminArea(Middleware):

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (false === auth()->user()->hasRole('admin')) {
           // return redirect()->route('warning.wrong.role');
            return "Your not autorized";
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Kernel.php

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
      ...
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminArea::class,
    ];
```

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: As per laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware you have to define the before or after inside the middleware and in route use ->middleware('name_of_middleware');

Comment: @Zeus yes, i see, i made this change but now gives me in the page this error 'ErrorException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 135:
Trying to get property of non-object'

Comment: Is the route inside the web middleware?

Comment: @Zeus by default in the laravel 5.2 is already inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first answer here might be helpful:
[Middleware for admin role](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/user-admin-authentication)